# Dynamically Load Data for IONIC List on Scroll

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I was wondering if there is a way in IONIC via native components to create a dynamic list.
By that i mean i can go and load the initial set of data and rows and display and when user reaches a certain point i can load additional Data into the list to avoid having to wait longtime for all data to load at once. In my Angular Apps i do it via AG grid which calls it virtual scroll. I searched but could not find anything on that on IONIC site.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic's Infinite Scroll is what you are looking for

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll

Here is the example from the Ionic Docs

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-button (click)="toggleInfiniteScroll()" expand="block">
    Toggle Infinite Scroll
  </ion-button>

  <ion-list></ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonInfiniteScroll } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'infinite-scroll-example',
  templateUrl: 'infinite-scroll-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./infinite-scroll-example.css']
})
export class InfiniteScrollExample {
  @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;

  constructor() {}

  loadData(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Done');
      event.target.complete();

      // App logic to determine if all data is loaded
      // and disable the infinite scroll
      if (data.length == 1000) {
        event.target.disabled = true;
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  toggleInfiniteScroll() {
    this.infiniteScroll.disabled = !this.infiniteScroll.disabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26762666)

Comment: While I agree with that, he is asking for the component itself not how to implement it. A link to the Ionic Docs along with the component name I feel answers sufficiently

Comment: and would it not be a better answer if the component example was posted? Just trying to help you make a better answer to get an upvote. Dont mind me then.

Comment: Just did that as you were replying

Comment: well I didn't downvote. Maybe someone else did because this was in the Q for low quality answers